# STM32 flashing disabled after flashing a code without R/W protection

Tags: embedded, stm32

I have some experience of StdPeriph libraries usage for programming stm32. But now I tried STM32Cube HAL with STM32CubeMX code generator. I generated a project with this options:

- Middleware: FreeRTOS and FatFS via SDIO
- Compiler is GCC
- stm32f103ret6 MCU

I imported generated code to Eclipse environment. I made a binary and flashed it with "st-flash write ..." as usual. My test program successfuly wrote to USART1 "Hello" in cycle - this is no problem. But then, when I tried to flash another code, it failed with "unknown chip id". If I manually connect NRST to GND, st-flash gives:

```
...Flash: 0 bytes (0 KiB) in pages of 2048 bytes
```

Full output:

```
2015-06-14T16:07:29 INFO src/stlink-common.c: Loading device parameters....
2015-06-14T16:07:29 INFO src/stlink-common.c: Device connected is: F1 High-density device, id 0x10036414
2015-06-14T16:07:29 INFO src/stlink-common.c: SRAM size: 0x10000 bytes (64 KiB), Flash: 0 bytes (0 KiB) in pages of 2048 bytes
```

I tried to use ST-Link Utility from Windows, but it cannot connect to this MCU to change option bytes (connection to another devices with stm32 works well). 
I tried to flash through USART1, but it failed.

Source code I flashed, of course, does not contain any read/write protection enabling. I tried 2 another MCU, but this error was reproduced.

How can I unbrick by MCUs and flash anything?

Comment: Some MCUs include circuitry (one or more **specific** bits on flash) to prevent unauthorized access to the contents of flash memory. When security is engaged (those bits are set to a specific value), the flash is considered a secure resource and can no longer be reprogrammed. You should pray to your favorite god or goddess that this is not the case that you're in. Another way to reach this scenario is by setting the Flash Protection Register, which is also mapped to some flash address. You should be able to revert from this scenario by reprogramming this flash address.

Comment: I know you wrote "without R/W protection", but even if your code does not explicitly set R/W protection enabled, you may have programmed it directly into the flash while attempting to program your code (into the wrong address or something).

Comment: If R/W protection is set anyway, I should be able to remove it for example through ST-Link Utility from Windows, isn't it? But I cannot even connect to my device...

Comment: Just had the exact same problem (on a different MCU though), about two weeks ago. The reason was that we wrote to the Flash-Secure byte (2 bits to be accurate). Now, it can be undone if your **already-programmed** application deploys the backdoor mechanism that comes along with this Security feature. Otherwise, the MCU is no longer accessible through JTAG (or any other means for that matter). In other words, which must refrain from using here, checkout Con Air (the movie) and search for Pinball's quote starting with "I don't know how to tell you this, Cyrus...".

Comment: But just to remove all doubts, I suggest that you refer to the STM32 data-sheet and see if that Security feature even exists on this MCU. Search for *Flash Security* or something similar...

Comment: The STM32 chips can be unlocked, however you need a tool which does the first part of the connection with reset asserted, then directs you to release it.  The windows tool will when the right options are selected, while that has often not worked under texane's otherwise excellent code (I once had an experimental modification to do this, but it caused other issues so only used that version for unbricking).  FWIW with many other brands nRST is normally wired to the programmer alongside the SWD clock and data and asserted by it as a matter of course.

Comment: So releasing reset at some moment is mandatory for this procedure? Could you give me patched texane's code for unbricking?

Comment: As I understood from datasheet, STM32 can protect flash memory pages, but "option bytes" are always changeable? So I don't understand... Another point is HOW my MCU was locked by standard example generated by stm32cubemx...

Comment: The STM32F can be protected at different levels. Unfortunately, this is a **O**ne **T**ime **P**rogrammable cell in the option bytes. The reference manual (you will not find that in the datasheet) is a bit unclear on howto, where, etc. However, protection might include JTAG, bootloader (change the `MODE` pins, etc.). You should try to verify what you have programmed actually. It can be very well you bricked the device (there is no `ERASE` pin as for some Atmel-SAMs.

Comment: The "full output" does not include the part "unknown chip id" which is probably more useful.  I am not sure that the problem is even that the device is locked.STM32F1xx has JTAG debug lock and memory read-out protection, and can be unlocked, but doing so performs an automatic bulk-erase.  In my experience, using Segger J-LInk, reading a locked chip results in all bytes reading out 0xFF not "unknown chip id" - that sounds more like the programmer is set to program a different device that the one attached.  This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159264/st-link-unknown-chip-id-0x6423 may help.

Comment: Thanks to all! I found a solution, but I don't understand it. I made a mistake when tried to flash trough USART1 (left BOOT1 'on air', but GND needed). After I set BOOT1 to zero, Flash Loader Demonstrator utility erased MCU. But this tool shown me that ALL flash memory pages were unlocked for read and write! So only SWD programming was partialy blocked, and this is strange...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the pin assignments for the JTAG/SWD pins correctly (e.g. SYS_JTDI, SYS_JTDO-TRACESWO, etc.) on the pinout tab of STM32CubeMX, the generated code will not disable JTAG/SWD.

Comment: Shortcut: Under Peripherals/SYS/Debug, you can choose the type of interface you will use, and it will set the correct pin assignments.

Answer (score 5):

I found a root cause!

This is a HAL initialization function, generated by STM32CubeMX:

```
void HAL_MspInit(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 0 */

  __HAL_RCC_AFIO_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4);

  /* System interrupt init*/
/* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);

    /**DISABLE: JTAG-DP Disabled and SW-DP Disabled 
    */
  __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_SWJ_DISABLE();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 1 */
}
```

I didn't notice this simple lines!

```
/**DISABLE: JTAG-DP Disabled and SW-DP Disabled 
*/
__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_SWJ_DISABLE();
```

This macros totally disables SWD and JTAG programming, look at `stm321xx_hal_gpio_ex.h`:

```
#define __HAL_AFIO_REMAP_SWJ_DISABLE()  MODIFY_REG(AFIO->MAPR, AFIO_MAPR_SWJ_CFG, AFIO_MAPR_SWJ_CFG_DISABLE)
```

I didn't found any checkbox in CubeMX to disable/enable SWD/JTAG, so this is **the only behavior** of code generator! Pay attention to this point when using STM32CubeMX!

Comment: Check the SYS bullet under Peripherals tree and set Debug -> Serial-Wire (default - disabled)

Answer (score 2):

It's (BURIED) under Pinout | SYS | Debug of STM32CubeMX...set to Serial Wire or whatever.